# Node.js and unpublished global modules

Tags: node.js, module

`npm install -g xyz` installs the module xyz gets to what I would call a 'global modules directory' i.e. `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` in Windows 7.

However, there seems to be no way to make all my node projects use these modules.

If I have a project in `C:\temp\test.js` then `require('xyz')` cannot find the module.

1. Setting environment variable `NODE_PATH` to the above global modules directory doesn't help
2. AFAIK `npm link` only works with published modules not my own unpublished ones

Short of putting all my projects in a sub-folder of the global modules directory (so that node traverses up and finds node_modules/) is there any way of re-using those global modules?

If so, what is the point of -g and 'global' modules?

Comment: What did you set `NODE_PATH` to? Your configuration is definitely wrong, if you install a module globally (in the `$NODE_PATH`) you can use it in all of your apps

Comment: I though so too. But, as I say, it's set to the global node_modules folder (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules). I've also tried setting it to C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm to no avail.

C:\temp\node>node.exe
> process.env.node_path;
'"C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules"'
> require('couchapp');
Error: Cannot find module 'couchapp'

Answer (score 1):

Global modules are only used for command line tools. For example if you install Express.js globally you can use `express --session` to create new projects. If you need to require express in your project then you need to install it in the local node_modules directory.

Comment: I see that now but then the supposed global node_modules folder would better be named 'node_apps'. It's confusing as it is and it needlessly prevents a true global modules feature.